# Calling a function from awk with variable input location

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have a bunch of different files.We have used "|" as delimeter All files contain a column titled CARDNO, but not necessarily in the same location in all of the files. I have a function called data_mask. I want to apply to CARDNO in all of the files to change them into NEWCARDNO.

I know that if I pass in the column number of CARDNO I can do this pretty simply, say it's the 3rd column in a 5 column file with something like:

```
awk -v column=$COLNUMBER '{print $1, $2, FUNCTION($column), $4, $5}' FILE
```

However, if all of my files have hundreds of columns and it's somewhere arbitrary in each file, this is incredibly tedious. I am looking for a way to do something along the lines of this:

```
awk -v column=$COLNUMBER '{print #All columns before $column, FUNCTION($column), #All columns after $column}' FILE
```

My function takes a string as an input and changes it into a new one. It takes the value of the column as an input, not the column number. Please suggest me Unix command which can pass the column value to the function and give the desired output.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please wrap your samples and code in  CODE TAGS and be more clear in your question please.

Comment: First of all I haven't downvoted. Second thing if people are trying to help you(without anything in return) then it is OP(original poster)'s duty to provide all information. I always encourage people not discourage which is why I am requesting you again here to post more details.

Comment: Also posting sample(s) of input and expected output too in CODE TAGS will help us understanding your requirement more.

Comment: @OnkarTiwari lose the attitude and be grateful for the good, well-intentioned advice. See [ask] if it's not clear what's required to ask a question in this forum.

Comment: @OnkarTiwari, update your posts, don't mention your inputs/outputs in comments please.

Comment: Thanks Ravinder. input is <code>id|name|designation
11|onkar|consultant
12|wipro|company
13|capgemini|IT
</code> and if user enters 2 means second column then  output will be like  <code>  id|name|designation
11|sqmbr|consultant
12|itzaw|company
13|khvlipkoi|IT
ignore the header names.

Comment: Dear Morton, I will definitely learn the rules of stackoverflow with the time. I made my account today only. I am looking for answer since morning. Ravinder has replied in the same way in another question thats why i had replied on that way.

Comment: Yes we get a lot of newcomers who don't understand the rules of the forum or how to ask a question in a way that's most likely to get a lot of good responses and result in them getting the best possible answer so Ravinder and others do frequently have to help them get to that point. Your response of `What you are not getting? is it your standard response for all questions? either you help or ignore. dont downvote and demotivate people here. what you dint get in question?` to his helpful feedback was simply unbelievable. You might want to delete that comment and then provide the missing [mcve].

Comment: To be clear if you had done as Ravinder suggested you'd undoubtedly have answers right now from multiple people, including exactly the solution you need, and you wouldn't be playing peel the onion with @kvantour as he struggles to understand what exactly it is you want to do (to be fair though, that's his own fault for trying to answer a question without the missing [mcve] that'd clearly and simply show us exactly what's needed!).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, the first row of the file is the header and one of those columns is named `CARDNO`. If this is the case then you just search for the header in that file and process accordingly.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|";c=1}
     (NR==1){while($c != "CARDNO" && c<=NF) c++
             if(c>NF) exit
             $c="NEWCARDNO" }
     (NR!=1){$c=FUNCTION($c)}
     {print}' <file>
```

As per comment, if there is no header in the file, but you know per file, which column number it is, then you can simply do:

```
awk -v c=$column 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$c=FUNCTION($c)}1' <file>
```

Comment: Thanks. We have already removed header before calling the function.Could you please tell me the updated command. Also please tell me do I need to replace function name?

Comment: This is one of the reasons why a [mcve] is required in your question, to avoid peeling the onion on every-evolving vague requirements. @kvantour - have fun... :-).

Comment: @OnkarTiwari I don't really understand your question. If there is no header anymore, there is no possible way to identify the column, unless it has a set of unique properties. Somewhere we need to be able to identify the column.

Comment: Dear kvantour, Thanks for your quick reply. Could you please suggest the same without considering the header names. consider the column position only. Suppose if user wants to mask second column then he will enter 2. We have redesigned file before calling function and there is no header on it. We have to mask data based on column position. and position will be variable. it will not be same in every file.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. My function is data_mask() {

  col_val=$1
  }  . how to call it. it is not taking value as an argument

Comment: user will input column number .and our function will receive value of that column. function is not parameterized . it is receiving the value in $1. so user will input the column number and value of that column should be passed.

Comment: Dear @OnkarTiwari, we are happy to help people out but at the moment I am a bit puzzled. It looks to me that your original question, and how most people understood it, is not compatible with your actual requirements. Please update your original question to reflect these "new" requirements.  Eg. In your question you talk about `FUNCTION($column)` but now it appears that `data_mask()` does not take any arguments. As you see, this is not compatible or we miss understood it. Please give us some simplified example file and what your intentions are.

Comment: Hi, my function name is data_mask. It is not taking any parameter. But inside the function (here function is keyword)  we are receiving parameter. We are passing this parameter from our awk command. Requirement is ,user will input the column no which he want to mask. Our awk command will pass the value of that column no to data_mask. Remaining field would be same. We have to make a command which can pass value of that column to data_mask as an input.command can be anything.It can be awk ,sed etc . By the way thank you very much for your help and valuable time.

Comment: Hi @kvantour my collegue has asked the same question and provided every possible details. Could you please help on the same. my id has been blocked. I can not ask further question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50703541/performance-tuning-in-unix-script-is-very-slow