# performance tuning in unix.Script is very slow

Tags: unix, awk, sed

We have a function named as data_mask. it accept string and mask it. in our file we want to mask any column based on the input given by user. for that we are splitting the columns of file in 3 parts.

```
while read p; do

  if [[ $line -le $skip_line ]]; then
    echo "$p" >> $outputfile
  else
    pre_str=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f1-$((colnum - 1))`
    column_value=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f$colnum`
    post_str=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f$((colnum + 1))-$totalcol`
    echo "column_value=$column_value"
     maskvalue=$(data_mask "$column_value")
    echo $pre_str"|"$maskvalue"|"$post_str >> $outputfile


  fi

  line=$((line + 1))

  done <$temp_outputfile
```

here colnum is the number input by user.data_mask function we are calling by passing the value of column entered by user.
Suppose user enter 5 then pre_str will store the column  from 1 to 4. column_value will store the column which needs to be masked. post_str will store the column after the masked column. here we are splitting the column value and then concatenating it. Any better way to do it. it is taking lot of time.

Can we change the below lines through awk or sed. We are splitting everyline and reading data line by line.

```
 pre_str=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f1-$((colnum - 1))`
    column_value=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f$colnum`
    post_str=`echo $p | cut -d'|' -f$((colnum + 1))-$totalcol`
    echo "column_value=$column_value"
     maskvalue=$(data_mask "$column_value")
    echo $pre_str"|"$maskvalue"|"$post_str >> $outputfile
```

Below is the sample input:-

```
11|Shrut|consultant
12|wipro|company
13|capgemini|IT
```

if user enters 2 then output should be

```
11|sqmbr|consultant
12|itzaw|company
13|khvlipkoi|IT
```

Algorithm for masking is written in the function data_mask. we have to change only the above code.
Below is the our data_mask function.

```
data_mask() {

  col_val=$1
  l_ret_str=""
  l_an=0
  l_lp=0
  l_mod=0
  absnum=0
  austart=65
  auend=90
  aclsize=26
  alstart=97
  alend=122
  nstart=48
  nend=57
  nclsize=10

  l_lp=`expr length "$col_val"`
  if [[ $l_lp -ne 0 ]]; then
    for i in `eval "echo {1..$l_lp}"`
    do
      single_char=$(SUBSTR "$col_val" $i)
      ascii_num_val=$(ASCII "$single_char")
      l_mod=$((l_mod+ascii_num_val))
    done

    l_mod=$((l_mod % nclsize))

    for i in `eval "echo {1..$l_lp}"`
    do
      single_char=$(SUBSTR "$col_val" $i)
      ascii_num_val=$(ASCII "$single_char")
      l_an=$ascii_num_val
      tempvar=$((l_an - l_lp - l_mod - i))
      absnum=$(ABS $tempvar)
      if [[ $l_an -ge $austart && $l_an -le $auend ]]; then
        tempmodval=$((absnum % aclsize))
        tempasciival=$((austart + tempmodval))
        l_ret_str=$l_ret_str$(CHR $tempasciival)
      elif [[ $l_an -ge $alstart && $l_an -le $alend ]]; then
        tempmodval=$((absnum % aclsize))
        tempasciival=$((alstart + tempmodval))
        l_ret_str=$l_ret_str$(CHR $tempasciival)
      elif [[ $l_an -ge $nstart && $l_an -le $nend ]]; then
        tempmodval=$((absnum % nclsize))
        tempasciival=$((nstart + tempmodval))
        l_ret_str=$l_ret_str$(CHR $tempasciival)
      else
        tempmodval=$((absnum % nclsize))
        tempasciival=$((austart + tempmodval))
        l_ret_str=$l_ret_str$(CHR $tempasciival)
      fi

    done
  fi
  echo "$l_ret_str"
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please wrap your sample input and sample output in CODE TAGS a button `{}` and let us know then.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 I have done the required changes

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 Could you please help on the above question. It is actually important and I am not able to resolve this issue. I am struggling a lot.

Comment: @Shruthi sharma, could you please sample of input and sample of expected output in your post in CODE TAGS as it is not clear to me.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 I have added the input and output in question.

Comment: This same question is appearing again and again and it seems you're not using the advice given.  So, why bother asking?  Using extensive string operation in `bash` is an anti-pattern.  The whole shebang can be done is a simple `awk` script which will outperform this at least 100 fold.

Comment: What is going on? We have you and another user, [@ONKARTIWARI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8867454/onkar-tiwari), both repeatedly asking questions about a function named "data_mask" (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50680654/1745001), ignoring the advice you're given, and then asking for more help to continue doing the wrong thing including now how to solve the obvious, predictable performance problems you're having by doing the wrong thing! Just take the advice you've already been given and build on it.

Comment: @Shrutisharma downvotes don't stop you from asking questions. All he had to do was provide the missing information, which should have been tricial, but he chose not to and so accumulated multiple downvotes and at least 5 close-as-unclear votes from multiple people because no-one could figure out what he was asking about. I'm not making fun in the slightest, I'm trying to figure out what it is you need. You must've noticed by now that your current approach to asking questions isn't working so why not take a minute to simply provide what everyone is asking you for so we can actually help you.

Comment: Dear @EdMorton did you read the question I have asked? I have provide every details. script, input , output etc. it is just we are helpless, thats why we are trying everything. we are not enjoying here by getting humiliation.

Comment: Of course I've read it. You've now posted sample input/output that seem completely disconnected from the 3 bewilderingly large, complicated shell scripts you've posted and you've told 2 people with 2 completely different answers (both of which don't simply do what you asked for wrt converting your input to your output) that you will implement them both. Your output has fields like `sqmpr` that don't appear in your input, and you say you want to print column 2 but the output has 3 columns. Recently Onkar was talking about an awk function now yours is shell - none of it makes any sense!

Comment: As per client requirement we can not change function. We were told blindly to increase the performance. we have to reduce the iteration and splitting of columns of file.

Comment: Can you ping me in chat. I am not allowed to ping. I will explain you in details.

Comment: OK, so say "I have a shell function named data_mask() that we cannot change and given input X outputs Y. Our calling code is inefficient and we need to improve it.". Now add the sample input and expected output, show what you've tried so far, and ask for help. It's that simple. There's no point posting a 50-line function that cannot be changed and so isn't part of what you're asking for help with, it just makes it that much harder to figure out what you DO need help with. I'm sorry but chat won't help - we just need you to post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Dear @EdMorton file will have n number of columns. user will input which column he wants to mask. as per my data user entered 2 and second column got masked. so in output you can see sqmpr . this is done by data_mask function. we have to call it. I am just looking for efficient way to call without splitting files. He thought about awk thats why he mentioned. if awk helps please suggest the command or please suggest some alternatives. the thing is we cant replace or change our function. the while loop is the way we are calling now. can it be replaced?

Comment: Dear @EdMorton I put the function because one person who was answering asked for it. I edited my question after the people who were answering suggested me to do. otherwise in my original question that was not mentioned.

Comment: Yeah, we're all struggling to accept that you're asking for a performance improvement but can't change the one thing that would vastly improve the performance. So you're saying all you need to do is take a number like `2` and call the shell function `data_mask()` on field 2 and print the result? OK I'll post an answer for that.

Comment: if user enters 2 then we have to pass the value of second column to data_mask() function. here like  in my example in first row shrut should be passed , not 2.

Comment: OK, I posted an answer. If that doesn't do what you want then **please** update your question to clarify your requirements and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sure @EdMorton . Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton Thank you. I need one more help. In the below answer you have suggested how to pass value to function for random column through gawk.. Could you please suggest me corresponding awk command with delimeter "|". please tolerate me once more. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769957/apply-a-function-to-one-column-only-with-a-variable-location

Comment: Hi @EdMorton can I get corresponding awk command when delimeter is "|".                                                                               gawk -v col=4 '{print gensub("([[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){" col-1 "})[^[:space:]]+","\\1"toupper($col),"")}' file

Comment: No. One question, one answer. If you have a new question then post it as such with it's own [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output. Please read [ask].

Comment: I see we have another vague, nebulous question with no sample input and expected output posted by your colleague, @OnkarTiwari - https://stackoverflow.com/q/50712353/1745001. Please, please sit down together and read the feedback you've had from your previous questions and the guidelines on [ask] so you can get the most out of the people who are so far still willing to try to help you on  this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you're looking for:

```
$ cat tst.sh
data_mask() { printf '%s\n' "${1//?/_}"; }

col="$1"
file="$2"
skip=2

sep='|'
tail +"$(( skip + 1 ))" "$file" |
cut -f "$col" -d "$sep" |
while IFS= read -r val; do
    data_mask "$val"
done |
awk -F"$sep" -v OFS="$sep" -v col="$col" -v skip="$skip" '
    NR==FNR { a[NR]=$0; next }
    FNR > skip { $col = a[FNR-skip] }
    { print }
' - "$file"
```

My data_mask() just converts every char to an underscore - obviously replace it with your real function.

As previously stated if you re-write data_mask() in awk (which looks like it'd be a trivial task) then the rest can also be done entirely in awk and then the execution will speed up literally 100-fold.

Comment: thanks @Ed Morton . much appreciated help. I will try the same in my output. even data_mask() function made by you is amazing. but sometimes we have to listen our clients. whether they know  or they dont know they are always right. Thank you very much for tolerating us and your kind help.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton. We are grateful for your help. Could you please do the little modification in script. if user wants to skip first n lines like header and all, how to embed that part in script.

Comment: Those line should be part of output but function should not be called for them

Comment: OK, I updated the answer to skip converting the first 2 lines. Again - if you simply provided truly representative sample input and expected output in your question we wouldn't have to go back and forth peeling the onion to figure out your requirements and a solution. There is no header in the sample in your question so the updated script is untested.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton . Thank you very much. I have used your yesterdays code by excluding header and putting it later. it worked and code was accepted by client. Now updated code is more efficient. Thank you very much . Much appreciated help in very difficult time.

Comment: I got now. Thanks Ed Morton. You are very kind and helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. Now that I think you understand what is required, please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50712353/1745001 to see if you can help Onkar create an acceptable question.

Comment: I will help him in the same way you helped me. He was not able to solve the problem and was depressed. Now we have completed the script and handed over to client. Probably he will have time now to learn :). But Dear @Ed Morton...I can't express in words how much you helped us. No one was able to solve this issue in our team. And client wanted the solution which you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'd move the output redirection to the outside of the loop. Also read the data into an array and just replace the selected column "inline"

```
(   # run loop in a subshell so changing IFS does not affect rest of script
    IFS='|'
    while read -ra fields; do
        if (( line > skip_line )); then
            # subtract 1 since bash arrays are indexed starting from 0
            fields[colnum-1]=$(data_mask "${fields[colnum-1]}")
        fi
        echo "${fields[*]}"   # this will use $IFS to join the fields.
        ((line++))
    done <"$temp_outputfile" >"$outputfile"
)
```

This may not greatly increase the performance, if at all. Given that you're reading from a "temp" file, I suspect you're doing more disk IO than is necessary.

Perl is generally a lot faster than bash, but I'm not going to translate your code for you.

Comment: Thanks Glenn for your valuable time and help. I will implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a similar functionality in `awk` last week. It's crazy fast and does the job nicely.

```
function smartmatch(diamond, rough,   x, y) {
  for (x in rough) y[rough[x]]
  return diamond in y
}
function getrandchar(){
        charlist="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        return substr(charlist, int(rand()*51+1), 1);
}    
BEGIN{
        srand();
        split(fieldstr,fieldarr,",");
        OFS=FS;
}

#preserve the header if requested
header==1 && NR==1 {
        print $0;
}

header==1 && NR>1 || header==0{

        #loop through columns   
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){

                #check if this is a field we are scrambling
                if (smartmatch(i,fieldarr)){                      

                        #iterate through each character
                        for (j=1;j<=length($i);j++){

                                #if it's numeric then pick a random digit
                                if (substr($i,j,1) ~ /[0-9]/){
                                        printf "%s", int(10*rand());

                                #if it's not an alpha hen just print it
                                }else if(substr($i,j,1) ~ /[^a-zA-Z]/){
                                        printf "%s", substr($i,j,1);

                                #must be an alpha, generate a random character
                                }else{
                                        printf "%s", getrandchar();                                         
                                }
                        }

                        #complete the field
                        printf "%s", i!=NF ? OFS : "";
                }else{
                        #complete the line
                        printf "%s%s", $i, i!=NF ? OFS : "";
                }

        }
        printf "\n"
}
```

This replaces digits with a random digit and letters with a random letter (upper or lower case). It also preserves special characters (characters not in a-zA-Z).

Saving it `data_mask.awk` you can use it like:

```
 awk -v header="1" -v fieldstr="4,5,6" -f data_mask.awk your_file_here
```

`header="1"` tells it that there's a header and to preserve it. `fieldstr="4,5,6"` tells it to mask those columns.

Like any awk script, you can tell it the column delimiter when you call it with the `-F` flag, like `-F"|"` for pipe delimited data.

Example:

```
echo "this,is,a,test,567-harry,anemail@example.com" | awk -F"," -v header="0" -v fieldstr="4,5,6" -f data_mask.awk
this,is,a,vtKC,002-DOrpu,YFabCKk@pBwFXnl.Wjc
```

Comment: Thanks @JNevill. I will work on the same, thanks for your valuable time and help.